# ¿Por qué MongoDB 4.0.1 es mucho más lento que Mongodb 3.2

Tags: nodejs, mongodb

Había trabajado con `mongodb 3.2` y `Nodejs`

Por probar, me instalé la última versión de mongo, la 4.0.1, ejecuté un test de escritura (documentos muy simples con _id, date, docset_id (numerical)) , y en 3.2 se demora 1 a 1.5 segundo insertando 10000 registros.

Con mongodb 4 se demora 10, 15, 20, 30 segundos y va subiendo cada vez que pruebo, insertar los mismos 10000.

### Añado información de mi ambiente:

```
Intel core i7-4790k 8 core  4ghz
SSD storage 
Wired tiger para los dos tests
```

Los tests fueron ejecutados en el mismo equipo

Pruebas realizadas (en el mismo equipo):

- XFS FileSystem
- WiredTiger
- Intel Xeon E3-1230 v3 - 3.3 GHz - 4 core(s)
- NodeJS 8
- mongodb driver nodejs v 3.1.3
- Insertar 10000 simples documentos: {nombre: 'xxxx', docset_id: Número}

### Mongodb 3.2 Tests:

1. 1400 ms
2. 1215 ms
3. 1684 ms
4. 1020 ms
5. 2300 ms
6. 1230 ms

### Mongodb 4.0.1 (lo mismo para 3.6.6) Tests:

1. 12234 ms
2. 16456 ms
3. 27567 ms
4. 24870 ms
5. 26560 ms
6. 42654 ms

Comment: Sube los tests de rendimiento

Comment: si es mas lento pero es por el sistema y la forma que guarda los archivos los hace mas seguros, lei hace algun tiempo un post en cuanto lo tenga respondere, o alguien de la comunidad me imagino que lo hara

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/4.0/ en el release chequea que esta deprecado NMAPv1 (es la forma como guardaba en archivos mongodb) ademas que agregaron transacciones eso indica que lo hace mas robusto pero con "ligera" lentitud

Comment: en mi pregunta especifiqué que en los dos casos estoy usando wiredTiger. Y no estoy usando la funcionalidad de transacciones. Para añadir más a mi pregunta, lo mismo pasa si instalo MongoDB 3.6. La verdad que no entiendo. Funcionan tan mal esas nuevas versiones, con el driver de NodeJS, o así mismo lentas son?

Comment: La diferencia es grandísima, y como digo lo peor es que con cada nueva inserción en el mismo proceso, se va haciendo más largo el tiempo que demora insertar la misma cantidad. Cantidad que no demora más de 2 segundos con la versión Mongodb 3.2 termina demorando practicamente 1 minuto con las versiones posteriores

Comment: sucede lo mismo con `bulk.insert()` ?

Comment: estoy probando un insert a la vez, porque ahí es donde se puede saber de verdad si la base de datos soportara el comportamiento real que tendrá la aplicación

Comment: cómo son los tests? un solo script? varios concurrentes? es secuencial ?

Comment: Sin ver los tests, sólo es posible opinar sin dar respuestas concisas.